# How to get all objects from App Engine datastore using JDO 3.0?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This [tutorial explains how to get object by id](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata) but how can I get all objects in datastore? Is it required to created list of keys and use loop to get all objects? Is it possible to use some kind of sql query for `PersistenceManager`? Something like `SELECT * FROM datastore_name`. What is right way?

Comment: Queries are limited to selecting by kind, or ancestor.  So you need a separate query for each entity type.  How you do this in JDO I am sure someone will tell you, or you can find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a class of kind User

```
List<User> users = null;

mgr = getPersistenceManager();
Query query = mgr.newQuery(User.class); // Will query all from User class. Replace User with your class

users = (List<User>) query.execute();
```

users will then contain a list of all type User objects. You can then do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use extents

```
Extent<ClassName> users = pm.getExtent(ClassName.class);
```